# nginx reverse proxy with fallback

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to setup nginx to reverse proxy to a server, but if the file doens't exist on server A to then have a fallback to server B where the file definitely will be.

I need to do a 2TB S3 migration and it would simplify the process if nginx could be setup this way.

Here is what I'm using as a reverse proxy config currently:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:100m
    inactive=30d  max_size=10g;
    server {
        location /image/ {
            proxy_pass             https://origin.example.com/;
            proxy_set_header    Host    origin.example.com;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_cache            STATIC;
            proxy_cache_valid      200  30d;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
            http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx Plus has Active Health Check capability. You can add the 2 servers to an upstream group, apply an active health check in respect of the URI for the file, and if a 404 error is returned, Nginx will mark that server as unhealthy, and all requests will flow to the other server in the group.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/#hc_active

However, that will bounce all your traffic to the other server.

If you have control of the upstream, you could also use `X-Accel`:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

If the file did not exist on the upstream, the upstream would return the `X-Accel-Redirect` header, which the reverse proxy would read, and request the file from the other server.